# Angular Material disabled input + Tooltip

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 <div>
    <mat-form-field *>
      <input matInput #filterBox (keyup)="searchBox(filterBox.value)" disabled />
      <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

<mat-button-toggle-group
      matTooltip="TESTING "
      #toggleButtons="matButtonToggleGroup"
      (click)="filterBox(toggleButtons.value)"
      multiple
    >
      <mat-button-toggle value="TEST1">TEST1</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="TEST2">TEST2</mat-button-toggle
      >

    </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

If button from button-toggle-group will be clicked I want input be  disabled. + If input will be disabled  I want see tooltip Any suggestion

Comment: First, you should use `[(ngModel)]` or `[formControl]` to link your input values into javascript variables. Then everything will be simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, for whatever reason, tooltips are also disabled on disabled elements.

Wrap your element and put the tooltip on the wrapper instead.

```html
<span matTooltip="Blarg">
    <button mat-raised-button disabled>Clickies</button>
</span>
```